# How do burnouts work?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In *Saints Row, The Third*, I can't figure out how points for burnouts work and how you can earn maximum respect from them.

To get one started, you hold your brake and accelerator in the car. Even then though sometimes the game doesn't award anything for a burnout. It doesn't even seem consistent how it starts awarding points for it. At one point I thought the #/12 counter meant that if you did one for 12 seconds, you would get maximum respect, but that's not the case. I've also tried doing 12 doughnuts thinking that was maybe it. The most points I've ever been awarded is around 5 of 12 or 6 of 12, but nothing higher. Is there a way to earn all 12 of 12 possible points?

Comment: Were you doing this with an off the street car or an upgraded one from your garage?

Comment: @CyberSkull Off the street car. I'd have to try it in an upgraded one to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hmm. I think I recall doing a burnout with a Knoxville (4 person cart found at airport and used by mascots).

Comment: @CyberSkull so you got 12/12 in one? I can do a burnout in most any vehicle and get at least some score (normally), but I can't figure out what it is that triggers the scoring.

Comment: I don't recall the score, just that something popped up that said burnout. I was using the Knoxville to fill out my power slides challenge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maximizing respect from burnouts can be fairly difficult. The reason for this is:

**Your score is determined by the number of people cheering for your burnout.**

Yep, you read that right. The more people you have clapping, shouting, and fist-pumping at your burnout, the higher your respect bonus will be.

Comment: but also you have to have 12 people all at the same time. If someone leaves then the counter stops, until that someone is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of people who are around and witness you doing the burnout.

Answer (score 0):

as you do a burnout and you get to six keep doing a burnout but use nitrous while doing so and you get max 40 respect

Comment: Is there a reliable way to get to 6? It would be nice to know how to do it every time, then your nitro trick would be easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

It's the amount of people who notice you performing a burnout. To get a 3 star rate go to a highly populated area.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said.