# Where is a populated area to burnout?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Related: [How do burnouts work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46269/how-do-burnouts-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

I was wondering where can you find populated areas for burnouts in Saints Row the Third.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially just need pedestrians walking on the sidewalk - the more, the better.

There's not a particularly populated area I can suggest in the game, just drive around a bit in downtown, and find a spot where people are walking around.